# If $\alpha\ne1,\alpha^6=1$ and $\sum_{r=1}^6 {^6}C_r\alpha^{r-1}=x,$ then find the value of $|x|$.

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, contest-math

The following question is taken from the practice set of JEE exam.

> If $\alpha\ne1,\alpha^6=1$ and $\sum_{r=1}^6 {^6}C_r\alpha^{r-1}=x,$ then find the value of $|x|$.

$$\sum_{r=1}^6 {^6}C_r\alpha^{r-1}=x\\\implies {^6}C_1\alpha^0+{^6}C_2\alpha^1+{^6}C_3\alpha^2+{^6}C_4\alpha^3+{^6}C_5\alpha^4+{^6}C_6\alpha^5=x\\\implies {^6}C_1\alpha^1+{^6}C_2\alpha^2+{^6}C_3\alpha^3+{^6}C_4\alpha^4+{^6}C_5\alpha^5+{^6}C_6\alpha^6=\alpha x\\\implies {^6}C_0\alpha^0+{^6}C_1\alpha^1+{^6}C_2\alpha^2+{^6}C_3\alpha^3+{^6}C_4\alpha^4+{^6}C_5\alpha^5+{^6}C_6\alpha^6=\alpha x+{^6}C_0\\\implies (1+\alpha)^6=1+\alpha x$$

How shall I proceed next? I understand $\alpha$ is $6^{th}$ root of unity. How to use that here? Maybe $\alpha^6=1$ can be written as $$\alpha^6-1=0\\\implies (\alpha-1)(\alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=0$$

Also, $\alpha\ne1\implies \alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$. Is this of some help here? Thanks.

Comment: That's a thick polynomial equation.

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar Sorry I am not aware of that terminology.

Comment: I was just joking. By the way $\alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0\implies\alpha^3(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)+(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=0\implies(\alpha^3+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=0$

Comment: The question is flawed: $|x|$ can be $0, 1,$ or $28$, depending on which 6th root of unity is chosen.

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TonyK I agree. The question should have asked to find the value(s) of $|x|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly derived
$$ (1+\alpha)^6 = 1+\alpha x $$
(though it would have been easier to follow that derivation if you had kept the indexed sum notation in the intermediate lines).

From here it is probably simplest to leave the algebra and polynomials aside and simply *calculate* the value of the left-hand side based on which of the sixth roots of $1$ you have as $\alpha$. Using geometry to express $1+\alpha$ in polar coordinates in each case:
$$ \begin{array}{ccc} \alpha & 1 + \alpha & (1+\alpha)^6 \\ \hline
e^{i\pi/3} & \sqrt3 e^{i\pi/6} & -27 \\
e^{2i\pi/3} & e^{i\pi/3} & 1 \\
e^{3i\pi/3}=-1 & 0 & 0 \end{array} $$
and the last two roots are complex conjugates of the first.

Since $|\alpha|=1$ we have $|x|=|\alpha x|=|(1-\alpha)^6-1|$ which you can now compute directly.

As TonyK noted, the result depends on which root you choose for $\alpha$, so the question is strictly speaking ill-formed.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the wonderful answer. Can you please explain how you got $1+\alpha$ directly?

Comment: @aarbee: By drawing (well, actually imagining) diagrams with the parallelogram law. The parallelogram in both cases is made out of two equilateral triangles, but with different corners at the origin.

Comment: When you say 'parallelogram in both cases', which two cases are we talking about here?

Comment: @aarbee: the $\alpha=e^{i\pi/3}$ and $\alpha=e^{2i\pi/3}$ cases. In the third case, of course, adding $1$ to $-1$ doesn't need any diagram... (Perhaps I should have said, "In each case, the parallelogram is made ...")

Comment: To apply parallelogram law, we are taking one side as $1$ and the other as $\alpha$. So, the diagonal would be $1+\alpha$. Length of sides is unity. How did you directly visualize that the length of the diagonal is also unity? (Sorry if it's a silly doubt.)

Comment: In the $\alpha=e^{2i\pi/3}$ case the parallelogram consists of two of the six _equilateral_ triangles that the regular hexagon connecting the sixth roots decomposes into.
In the $\alpha=e^{i\pi/3}$ case we have again one of those equilateral triangles, with a similar triangle glued onto it on the _outside_ of the hexagon, so we're after the long diagonal. That long diagonal is twice the length of an altitude in a unit equilateral triangle, which I know to be $\sqrt3/2$.

Comment: [For full disclosure, what I _actually_ did at first to find the length was stupider than decomposing the parallelogram into equilateral triangles, namely adding explicitly to get $1+\alpha=1+\frac12+i\sqrt3/2$ and then calculating $$(1+\frac12)^2+(\sqrt3/2)^2 = \frac94+\frac34 = \frac{12}{4} = 3$$ That's still possible to do in one's head, but hardly _elegant_].

Comment: Hi. I understood that there would be equilateral triangles inside the hexagon. Now, I am not sure which parallelogram are we talking about here. I also don't know how we got $1+\alpha=\sqrt3e^{i\frac\pi6}$. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: There is one parallelogram for the $\alpha = e^{i\pi/3}$ case and another parallelogram for the $\alpha=e^{2i\pi/3}$ case. For the $e^{i\pi/3$ case the relevant parallelogram has two sides in common with the first equilateral triangle in the hexagon -- the two other sides of the parallelogram form another equilateral triangle _outside_ the hexagon. $1+\alpha$ is the long diagonal, whose length is two times $\sqrt3/2$ because the length of an altitude in a unit equilateral triangle is $\sqrt3/2$. The _angle_ of the diagonal is $\pi/6$ because the diagonal bisects the corner angles at its ends.

Comment: I am able to see this very clearly now. Thankyou very much. Indeed this method is quite elegant!

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$

$\implies\alpha^3(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)+(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=0$

$\implies(\alpha^3+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=0$

$\implies\alpha^3=-1, \alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$

Now from your equation, $(1+\alpha)^6=1+x\alpha$

$(1+\alpha)^6-1=x\alpha$

$\alpha(\alpha+2)(\alpha^2+3\alpha+3)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=x\alpha$

$0=x\alpha$

$\therefore|x|=0$

Here I didn't talked about the equation $\alpha^3=-1$. So this is just a special case.

Comment: You need to handle the case $\alpha^3=-1$ also.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh. Does that equation matter?

Comment: If $\alpha=-1$, then $x=1$.

Comment: And if $\alpha=\frac12(1+i\sqrt 3)$, then $x=-28/\alpha$. So yes, it matters.

Comment: @TonyK. Then let me edit the question to clear out that my answer is just a special case.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do the case where $\alpha$ is a *primitive* $6$-th root of unity.

Then $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^2-\alpha+1=0$,$\;$hence

\begin{align*}
x&=\sum_{i=1}^6 {\small{\binom{6}{i}}}\alpha^{i-1}
\\[4pt]
&=
\alpha^5+6\alpha^4+15\alpha^3+20\alpha^2+15\alpha+6
\\[4pt]
&=
(\alpha^3+7\alpha^2+21\alpha+34)(\alpha^2-\alpha+1)+(28\alpha-28)
\\[4pt]
&=
28\alpha-28
&&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\bigl(\text{since $\alpha^2-\alpha+1=0$}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=
28(\alpha-1)
\\[4pt]
&=
28\alpha^2
&&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\bigl(\text{$\alpha^2-\alpha+1=0$ implies $\alpha-1=\alpha^2$}\bigr)
\\[10pt]
\implies\;|x|&=
|28\alpha^2|
\\[4pt]
&=
28|\alpha|^2
\\[4pt]
&=
28
&&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\bigl(\text{since $|\alpha|=1$}\bigr)
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. How did you factorize? (second step after summation)

Comment: @aarbee: By polynomial long division.

Comment: ohkay, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Ranjit Kumar Sarkar gave the hint that $$\alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=\alpha^3(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=(\alpha^3+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)$$

Equating that to zero, I get $$\alpha=\omega,\omega^2,-1,-\omega,-\omega^2$$

where $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are the complex cube roots of unity.

Also, I had already got that $$(1+\alpha)^6=1+\alpha x ---(1)$$

@Troposphere suggested that I would get this equation faster if I had kept it in summation form. So, multiplying the given equation by $\alpha$, I get $$\sum_{r=1}^6 {^6}C_r\alpha^{r}=\alpha x\\\implies\sum_{r=0}^6 {^6}C_r\alpha^{r}=1+\alpha x\\\implies(1+\alpha)^6=1+\alpha x$$

Putting $\alpha=\omega$ in $(1)$, I get $$(1+\omega)^6=1+\omega x\\\implies (-\omega^2)^6=1+\omega x\\\implies 1=1+\omega x\\\implies|x|=0$$

I get the same result for $\alpha=\omega^2$

If I put $\alpha=-1$ in $(1)$, I get $$0=1-x\implies|x|=1$$

If I put $\alpha=-\omega$ in $(1)$, I get $$(1-w)^6=1-\omega x\\\implies\left(1-\frac{-1+\sqrt3i}2\right)^6=1-\omega x\\\implies\left(\frac{3-\sqrt3i}2\right)^6=1-\omega x\\\implies(\sqrt3)^6\left(\frac{1+\sqrt3i}{2i}\right)^6=1-\omega x\\\implies\frac{(\sqrt3)^6}{i^6}(-\omega^2)^6=1-\omega x\\\implies-27=1-\omega x\\\implies\omega x=28\implies|x|=28$$

I get the same result for $\alpha=-\omega^2$

Thankyou @Ranjit Kumar Sarkar, @quasi, @TonyK and @Troposphere for helping me think through it. Thanks.